# Server mirroring

Tags: hosting, mirroring

I'm about to start a new project and there is a hosting issue that has been discussed about mirroring the servers and having some backup.

A different team is proposing a mirroring option that has server A with one hosting provider and server B with another provider. They are working on a solution that will detect when server A is down so it can redirect to server B.

At first glance I'm not sure that's possible. At least what I think I know is that both servers would need to be within the same network or else, how can one domain work for two different DNS.

I've been doing some research and so far have come empty handed and was wondering if someone here could have some other input regarding this issue we are facing.

Thanks!

**-----[EDIT]-----**

Well, I'll try to clarify it a little bit more. (even for me)

Server A (SA) will be with hosting provider A (HPA).
Server B (SB) will be with hosting provider B (HPB).

Each server has the website and the database installed. SA is supposed to be the primary server and SB would just be there as a backup.

First, there should be some sort of process that is updating the database in SB.

So, when, and if, SA goes down, people entering the site should be redirected to SB, that it has, or should have, the database updated, so for visitors this redirection is "transparent".

Our question is if that idea of how it should work can be done through proxys, or load balancers, or just through DNS settings (the domain pointing to several IPs from different servers).

Answer (score 0):

Look into reverse proxy servers. It should be a simple configuration in nginx. 
They are typically used for load balancing, or providing backup sites/servers.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect solution but there can be another server which checks state of 2 servers hosting that project. This is a simple solution, but not perfect because if the mirrorer server is down, the same problem will occur again.